# How to modify "sign in" page using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to modify a regular sign in page. I want the input as lines instead of boxes. I am posting the link to the sign in page image I have right now:

http://prntscr.com/2o9n8z

Instead of the boxes here, I want the email address, password and confirm password fields as lines.

My CSS code is below:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

/* ---------- GENERAL ---------- */
/*
body {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    color: #999;
    font: 100%/1.5em sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}
*/


a {
    color: #999;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover { color: #1dabb8; }

fieldset {
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
}

input {
    border: none;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type="submit"] { cursor: pointer; }

.clearfix { *zoom: 1; }
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table; 
}
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }


#login-form {
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 300px;
}

#login-form h3 {
    background-color: #79a002;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#login-form fieldset {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 0 0 -1px -1px;
    padding: 0px;

}

#login-form fieldset:before {
    background-color: #fff;
    content: "";
    height: 8px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -4px 0 0 -4px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    width: 8px;
}

#login-form input {
    font-size: 14px;
}

#login-form input[type="email"],
#login-form input[type="password"] {
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    padding: 12px 10px;
    width: 300px;
}

#login-form input[type="email"] {
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

#login-form input[type="password"] {
    border-top: none;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
}

#login-form input[type="submit"] {
    background: #1dabb8;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #fff;
    float: right;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
}
```

I am modifying the  `border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;` in :

```
#login-form input[type="email"],
#login-form input[type="password"] {
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    padding: 12px 10px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

But I haven't been able to get the required output. What should I change in my code to get the required result ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/Q3Cq2/)**

```
#login-form input[type="email"], #login-form input[type="password"] {
    border:none; /* clear previous borders */
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdcdc; /* add bottom border */
    padding: 12px 10px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: add outline: 0; to remove the focus effect